# How to search gridview from date to date ASP.NET and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

This is my code which throws an error. I'm using input type text for my html coding.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=1GCAttendanceManagementSystem;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Attendances WHERE Date BETWEEN @From AND @To", con))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@From", SqlDbType.Date).Value = datepicker1.Text;
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@To", SqlDbType.Date).Value = datepicker2.Text;

           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           da.Fill(ds);

           GridView1.DataSource = ds;
           GridView1.DataBind();
       }
   }
}
```

[This is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCq4f.jpg)

Comment: Please update your question with the error you have

Comment: It says compilation error on this

Comment: if it jsays exactly "compilation error" it's definitely NOT sql server error

Comment: @sepupic ok I checked it. Then it says String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" also cannot be produced by SQKL Server. Meams that it's asp.net's error

Comment: @ffarihin Please use [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) so that Visual Studio can point out variable type mismatches for you. Once you've corrected those, you may have working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the `Text` which is a `string` and passing it on. Try Converting it to `DateTime` DateType first, like:

```
   DateTime oDateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker1.Text);
   DateTime oDateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker2.Text);
```

then pass them to `parameters`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@From", SqlDbType.Date).Value = oDateFrom;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@To", SqlDbType.Date).Value = oDateTo;
```

Hope that helps and Please, before you question again do read; [How should i ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ffarihin can you show us the error screenshot you are receiving?